# A asp.net page that tracks changes of a web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

An asp.net page that tracks a web page changes.
and if any changed occurred then it should send mail to my mailbox which I have configured using smtpclient.

I've coded for this task, but don't know where to place the code which section is executed always? Is there any possibility for this?

If not, then this page should be opened (viewed) always(24x7) or is there any way to open my asp.net page in the server?

Comment: You're looking for Google Alerts.

Comment: no....web page looking for some other particular website and particular purpose....

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want your "monitoring" code to run often (continuously?) and watch other pages to see if they change.

You will need something repetitive: like a windows service. This has been my option when I've needed to do this. Other options, although I have no personal experience, include Quartz.Net that allows you to schedule ASP.NET tasks.

However, this is precisely why RSS was invented. To allow others to *passively* monitor changes in websites.

Comment: but is there anyway to open the page in the server???so that it keep on looks for changes....

Comment: @Anand, I thought you said you coded that part. Yes, you make a .NET HTTP and review the response.